# TestFlight doesn't send invites to External users

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

After Apple updated Itunes Connect dashboard, TestFlight doesn't send invites to external testers. Anyone else has this issue?

Comment: looks like I've solved it. just need to click Save button.. kinda dumb..

Answer (score 1):

try this.

> itunesconnect.apple.com(with login) > My apps > (Your app) >
>   testflight > external testing > add build to test > (select your
>   build) > (add) > select your version > save